# Variable inside dataframe foreach gives null pointer exception in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having some issues when trying to execute a class function inside a "dataframe.foreach" function. My custom class is persisting the data into a DynamoDB table.

What happens is that if I have the following code, it won't work and will raise a "Null Pointer Exception" that points to the line of code where the "writer.writeRow(r)" is executed:

```
object writeToDynamoDB extends App {

    val df: DataFrame = ...
    val writer: DynamoDBWriter = new DDBWriter(...)
  
    df
      .foreach(
        r => writer.writeRow(r)
      )
}
```

If I use the same code, but having the code inside a code block or an if clause, it will work:

```
object writeToDynamoDB extends App {

    val df: DataFrame = ...
    
    if(true) {
        val writer: DynamoDBWriter = new DDBWriter(...)
  
        df
          .foreach(
            r => writer.writeRow(r)
          )
    }
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the variable scope. Even in IntelliJ the color of the variable is purple + Italic in the first case and "regular" grey in the second case. I read about it, and we have the method, field and local scope in Scala, but I'm can't relate that with what I'm trying to do.

Some questions after this introduction:

1. Can anyone explain why does Scala and/or Spark have this behaviour?
2. The solution here is to put some code inside a function, code block
   or a "fake" if clause as far as I know. Is there any possible issue regarding Spark properties (shuffles, etc)?
3. Is there any other way to do this type of operations?

Hope I was clear.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: I would bet the problem is because of the use of `App` instead of using a regular `main`  method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, your issue is caused by delayed initialization when using the `App` trait. [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) strongly discourage that:

> Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.

The reason can be found in the Javadocs of the `App` trait itself:

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the DelayedInit functionality, which means that fields of the object will not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

This basically means that `writer` is still uninitialized (so `null`) by the time the closure passed to `foreach` is created.

If you put respective code into a block, `writer` becomes a local variable and is initialized at the time when the block is evaluated. That way your closure will contain the correct value of `writer`. In this case it doesn't matter anymore when the code is evaluated, because everything get's evaluated together.

The correct and recommended solution is to use a standard `main` method for your Spark applications:

```
object writeToDynamoDB  {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val df: DataFrame = ...
    val writer: DynamoDBWriter = new DDBWriter(...)
    df.foreach(r => writer.writeRow(r))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But why does the second piece of code work properly? Why this "DelayedInit" behaviour is somehow avoided when, for instance, we put the code inside the if clause?

Comment: If you put that code into a block, `writer` becomes a local variable and is initialized at the time when the block is evaluated. That way your closure will contain the correct value of `writer`. In this case it doesn't matter so much anymore when the code is evaluated, because everything get's evaluated together.

Comment: There's lots of "magic" happening with usage of `DelayedInit` and as you experienced it can be very confusing. The `App` trait will therefore be deprecated in the near future and is replaced with a different mechanism in Scala 3. https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html

Comment: I've experienced other things that now probably can be explained by this. Even one or two are still open as we can't understand what's going on. Now I will give this main method a try in those cases also :)

Thanks a Lot!